# How to make Runescape work on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, chromium, runescape

I'm trying to play Runescape on Chromium, but it runs really slowly. I have IcedTea Java from the Software Center. I had to install it for the game to work at all, but it's not playable.

Does anyone have some good settings for me to use, or do I need a better way to have Java and Chromium work together so Runescape can run?

Memory: 4.8GB
CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620 Processor × 4
GPU: Gallium 0.4 on NV50 (driver) = Geforce 8800 GTS
OS type: 64bit

Comment: I do not play the game, but I ran into this article a while ago. Maybe that would help you: [How To Install RuneScape Linux Game Client In Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/how-to-install-runescape-linux-game.html). This is an article about installing an unofficial client on Ubuntu instead of running it in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 issues with this.

First, if you are using icedtea7/java7 then you will not be able to use OpenGL display mode unless you trick the Java binary to find its own library (which it for some reason is unable to find)

Secondly the 64 bit version of Java cannot use the client JVM which is designed for desktop Java applications. The 64bit version can only use the server JVM (which still runs the game but slow while textures are enabled) or other JVM that cannot run Runescape.

Lastly your graphic driver will cause issues because it will not be able to utilize OpenGL properly in Runescape. You are instead recommended to use the proprietary driver.

There is a [community run wiki article](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Known_Issues) that was created by us in the Runescape community tech support team to help Linux users play Runescape at the highest performance as possible.

There are even ways to run the Runescape client on Linux (either through Wine or native). [The RSU client](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Native_Clients) I made is an attempt to port the official client to Linux and apply as many fixes as possible

To finish off, the Linux users in Runescape have their own dedicated sticky thread in the Runescape forum where you will be able to get support for most issues.
QFC: 25-26-99-61985129

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to install the proprietary driver for your graphics card, as the OpenGL performance the opensource one delivers is sub-par.

Next, make sure you're not using Google Chrome if the IcedTea plug-in keeps crashing, as I have found it does not handle IcedTea too well in most occasions.

OpenJDK7 + IcedTea 7 is a fine combination to run Runescape, Oracle's Java is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Openj might be out of date, I downloaded 6 first, it wasn't the lastest version, so it would freeze and work at random times. I downloaded openj 7 and it worked fine after I downloaded. Download it on ubuntu software center. Hope it works!